# Security mechanisms of Debian and CentOS

Tags: debian, centos, iptables, selinux, firewalld

Are SELinux, FirewallD and Iptables preinstalled on Debian - Stretch (9 or 9.2) and CentOS (7.4-1708), or do I have to manually install them? 
Or where can I find it out?
Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: The answer to this may change over releases of these distributions; can you pin your question to specific versions?

Answer (score 1):

On Debian/Sid (and probably recent versions of stable Debian) you have the following packages:

```
 p  selinux-basics - SELinux basic support
 p  selinux-policy-default - Strict and Targeted variants of the SELinux policy
 p  selinux-policy-dev - Headers from the SELinux reference policy for
                         building modules
 p  selinux-policy-doc - Documentation for the SELinux reference policy
 p  selinux-policy-mls - MLS (Multi Level Security) variant of the SELinux policy
 p  selinux-policy-src - Source of the SELinux reference policy for customization
 p  selinux-utils - SELinux utility programs
 i  iptables - administration tools for packet filtering and NAT
 p  iptables-converter - convert iptables-commands from a file
                         to iptables-save format
 p  iptables-converter-doc - sphinx documentation for iptables-converter
 p  iptables-dev - transitional dummy package
 p  iptables-nftables-compat - iptables compat tools for nftables
 p  iptables-optimizer - sort iptables rules by packet counters
```

and many others (obtained with `aptitude search`). Of course you need to install them.

Comment: [AppArmor](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor) is also supported on Debian.